# Copying from array A elements which are not in array B

Tags: fortran

Suppose `A` is a one-dimensional array of non-repeated integers and suppose that `B` represents a proper subset of `A`. Is there a Fortran one-liner, perhaps using masks, to select the elements of `A` that are not in `B`? I mean, I want the set-theoretical complement of `B` with respect to `A`.

For example, given `A = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` and `B = [ 1, 2, 4 ]`, give me `C = [ 0, 3, 5 ]`.

Evidently this can be accomplished with explicit loops but I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want a one-liner?  If it's for clarity, that means we can't do certain things, and if it's for performance this may be a false premise.

Comment: It is for clarity. I want it to remember the mathematical set-builder syntax as much as possible.

Comment: Here's a clear one-liner `C = A .setdiff. B`.  Now all that remains is for someone to write the function and define the operator form. I doubt that anyone will come up with a one-liner of off-the-shelf-Fortran which is clearer.  This is a good example of the kind of purpose for which languages like Fortran support user-defined functions - to wrap code into nice little packages for clarity and ease of re-use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a Fortran one-liner, perhaps using masks, to select the elements of A that are not in B?

Yes, there is:

```
pack(a, [(all(b /= a(i)), i=1, size(a))])
```

Or the equivalent:

```
pack(a, .not.[(any(b == a(i)), i=1, size(a))])
```

However, bear in mind the comments from both @francescalus and @HighPerformanceMark, on *why do you want a one-liner?*:

- For clarity: This one-lines is pretty much clear in its intention, to be honest. A custom function/operator might be unnecessary in this case, except if you are doing it lots of times or want hide a different (more efficient, but not one-line) implementation.
- For performance: `a(i) == b` creates a temporary mask array of `size(b)` and performs 1 list traversal (redution) on it, for each element in `a`. Then, it creates a temporary array of `size(a)` dimension as the mask for the `pack` function, and traverses it (reduction) to construct the result array, with the final size. You could easily come up with a more performant algorithm, if it's worth it (very large arrays).

Tip: You will probably want an allocatable array to store the result, once that you don't know the size of the resulting array before-hand (the *automatic array allocation* feature of Fortran 2003 would be handy here). Another option would be passing, as third argument to the pack function, a vessel array with size of minimun `size(a)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. Since ``A`` doesn't have any repeated elements and since it contains ``B``, the size of the result is known, it is ``size(A)-size(B)``. I am looking for one-liners also to use them in initialization expressions. Performance is not an issue here, I suppose, since the involved arrays will be always very small (like 10 elements).